# Assistance in transposing data frame with an additional column using existing code in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I originally had @Kevin help me here on transposing the result of the example df below here: [Web scraping in python using BeautifulSoup - how to transpose results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57105346/web-scraping-in-python-using-beautifulsoup-how-to-transpose-results/57119226#57119226)

I added another column "CEO" and would like to recycle @Kevin 's code he provided earlier to incorporate this at the end. Here is the code that worked without the additional column:

```
    from collections import defaultdict
    aggregated_data = defaultdict(dict)
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        aggregated_data[row.Name][row.Category] = row.Rating
    aggregated_rows = [{"Company": name, **ratings} for name, ratings in aggregated_data.items()]
    result = pd.DataFrame(aggregated_rows)
    result.to_csv('text.csv')
```

I have been trying to incorporate it without success, here is what I have so far and producing errors:

```
from collections import defaultdict
    aggregated_data = defaultdict(dict)
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        aggregated_data[row.Name][row.Category] = [row.Rating][row.CEO]
    aggregated_rows = [{"Company": name, **ratings, ceo} for name, ratings, ceo_rating in aggregated_data.items()]
    result = pd.DataFrame(aggregated_rows)
    print(result)
```

Example df:

```
import pandas as pd
name = ['3M','3M','3M','3M','3M','Google','Google','Google','Google','Google','Apple','Apple','Apple','Apple','Apple']
number = ['3.8','3.9','3.5','3.6','3.8','4.2','4.0','3.6','3.9','4.2','3.8','4.1','3.7','3.7','4.1']
category = ['Work/Life Balance',' Salary/Benefits','Job Security/Advancement','Management','Culture','Work/Life Balance',' Salary/Benefits','Job Security/Advancement','Management','Culture','Work/Life Balance',' Salary/Benefits','Job Security/Advancement','Management','Culture']
ceo_rating = ['85%','85%','85%','85%','85%','86%','86%','86%','86%','86%','84%','84%','84%','84%','84%']
cols = {'Name':name,'Rating':number,'Category':category, 'CEO':ceo_rating}
df = pd.DataFrame(cols)
print(df)
```

Result:

```
      Name Rating                  Category  CEO
0       3M    3.8         Work/Life Balance  85%
1       3M    3.9           Salary/Benefits  85%
2       3M    3.5  Job Security/Advancement  85%
3       3M    3.6                Management  85%
4       3M    3.8                   Culture  85%
5   Google    4.2         Work/Life Balance  86%
6   Google    4.0           Salary/Benefits  86%
7   Google    3.6  Job Security/Advancement  86%
8   Google    3.9                Management  86%
9   Google    4.2                   Culture  86%
10   Apple    3.8         Work/Life Balance  84%
11   Apple    4.1           Salary/Benefits  84%
12   Apple    3.7  Job Security/Advancement  84%
13   Apple    3.7                Management  84%
14   Apple    4.1                   Culture  84%
```

Looking to make it like this:

```
 company name Work/Life Balance  Salary/Benefits Job Security/Advancement Management Culture  CEO
0           3M               3.8              3.9                      3.5        3.6     3.8    85%
1       Google               4.2              4.0                      3.6        3.9     4.2    86%
2        Apple               3.8              4.1                      3.7        3.7     4.1    84%
```

If anyone can assist that would be fantastic. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way `pivot_table`

```
s = df.pivot_table(index=['Name','CEO'],columns='Category',values='Rating',aggfunc='first').reset_index()
```

Comment: It works, but for some reason the categories go in different order than the rest of the data. Do you know why it could do this?

Comment: @g3lo you can always using sort_index get the order back

Comment: could you kindly advise what the code is, I will mark it as complete. I am really new, only started 2 days ago.

Comment: @g3lo you you mean the columns dose not follow the order  ?

Comment: @g3lo that can be done with reindex like s=s.reindex(columns=[your own order here])

Comment: Thank you and yes thats what I meant.